# Accessing a user's contacts with super administrator's OAuth token

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api, google-oauth

I know if a super administrator grants access to an application, that application (using OAuth) can access any user's (with that domain) calendar.

Does the same apply to a user's contacts (not shared contacts)?  From my testing, I keep getting 403 Forbidden, meaning it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the scope defined correctly for using the contact API?
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#authorizing_requests_to_the_api_name_service